# XGBoost tweedie regression objetive from scratch

Tags: regression, xgboost

I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of the tweedie loss function and how it is used in XGBoost. So, I tried to implement it from scratch. I started by examining the [original implementation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/730bc1f68852927c07b1f2ed8ff00bf3e28e448f/src/objective/regression_obj.cu#L596).

I think the important part is

```
bst_float grad = -y * expf((1 - rho) * p) + expf((2 - rho) * p);
bst_float hess = -y * (1 - rho) * std::exp((1 - rho) * p) + (2 - rho) * expf((2 - rho) * p);
```

I used these formulas to create a custom objective in Python following the [documentation on custom objective functions](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html#customized-objective-function).

```
def custom_tweedie(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix, rho: float = 1.5):
    """Custom squared error objective function for XGBoost"""
    y = dtrain.get_label()
    scores = np.log(predt)
    exp_1_score = np.exp((1 - rho) * scores)
    exp_2_score = np.exp((2 - rho) * scores)
    grad = -y * exp_1_score + exp_2_score
    hess = -y * (1 - rho) * exp_1_score + (2 - rho) * exp_2_score
    return grad, hess
```

`scores = np.log(predt)` is necessary, because XGBoost doesn't know the link function for custom objectives (see: [Reverse Link Function](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html#reverse-link-function) for reference).

Based on this implementation, I made  minimal example to compare my custom loss function with the vanilla implementation:

```
from functools import partial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import xgboost as xgb

# I know this isn't a tweedie distributed target variable,
# but both implementations should be equally good/bad.
X, y = fetch_california_housing(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape

def custom_tweedie(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix, rho: float = 1.5):
    """Custom squared error objective function for XGBoost"""
    y = dtrain.get_label()
    scores = np.log(predt)
    exp_1_score = np.exp((1 - rho) * scores)
    exp_2_score = np.exp((2 - rho) * scores)
    grad = -y * exp_1_score + exp_2_score
    hess = -y * (1 - rho) * exp_1_score + (2 - rho) * exp_2_score
    return grad, hess

# vanilla xgboost regression
params = {
    "seed": 42,
    "objective": "reg:tweedie",
    "tweedie_variance_power": 1.5,
    "tree_method": "gpu_hist",
    "max_depth": 3,
    "learning_rate": 0.01,
}

results_vanilla = {}
xgb.train(
    params=params,
    dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(X, y),
    num_boost_round=500,
    evals=[(xgb.DMatrix(X, y), "train")],
    evals_result=results_vanilla,
)

# custom xgboost regression
params = {
    "seed": 42,
    "tree_method": "gpu_hist",
    "eval_metric": "tweedie-nloglik@1.5",
    "max_depth": 3,
    "learning_rate": 0.01,
}

results_custom = {}
xgb.train(
    params=params,
    dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(X, y),
    num_boost_round=500,
    evals=[(xgb.DMatrix(X, y), "train")],
    evals_result=results_custom,
    obj=partial(custom_tweedie, rho=1.5),
)

x = np.arange(500)
y_vanilla = results_vanilla["train"]["tweedie-nloglik@1.5"]
y_custom = results_custom["train"]["tweedie-nloglik@1.5"]

fix, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
axs.plot(x, y_vanilla, label="vanilla")
axs.plot(x, y_custom, label="custom")
axs.legend()
axs.set_xlabel("Number of Trees")
axs.set_ylabel("Tweedie-nloglik")
axs.set_title("Comparison of the learinging curves of vanilla and custom objective")
```

[image: Learning curves of custom and vanilla tweedie objective]

Unfortunately, the custom and vanilla objective behave differently and I don't know why. Can some check my custom implementation and tell me what I am missing?